# Should the path you call a function from matter

Tags: php

I've got a function in a php file which is included in another php file using `require_once`

If I call the function from within the file it is written in, the function runs fine.

But if I call the same function from inside a different file where the file has been included via `require_once`, the function doesn't work properly. The problems revolve around executing a file in the function using `putenv` and `exec`.

Since the `exec` works fine when calling the function in the same way from within the file it's written in, but doesn't work when calling from a different file, I'd conclude that the problem is with my `require_once` include part, but I'm not sure what an alternative could be?

Comment: depends on the exec. If your exec runs something in the same folder as this PHP file, it will only append the exact script in the php file calling it. Then the exec part will point to an unknown path. That's why we use base_url

Comment: What's the contents of `exec()`? If it has file paths then this would probably be affected unless you put a full path in.

Comment: The exec runs from the folder where the function php file is in... but the php file calling the function is outside the directory

Comment: exec ("swetest -edir$sweph -b$utdatenow -ut$utnow -p0123456789DAttt -eswe -house$my_longitude,$my_latitude,$h_sys -flsj -g, -head", $out);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have this folder structure:

```
-file1.php //File where file2.php will be included
   scripts
    -file2.php //File with the function
    -virus.exe //File that the function runs
```

Running the function inside `file2.php` works since the path is correct, you point it to `"virus.exe"` or `"./virus.exe"`.

But when you include the `file2.php` in `file1.php`, the exact same code will be added to `file1.php`.

`file1.php` will try to `exec "./virus.exe"`, but it's not in the same folder as `file1.php`

That's why it won't work, and you need to use a base_url to find the correct file path.

Something like: `base_url() . "scripts/virus.exe"`

Comment: I tried moving the executable file into the directory where file1.php is, but it still doesn't work, shouldn't that work or will I have to use the base_url?

Comment: It will depend alot on your variable values, but using base_url is the best and most flexible way of doing it.

Comment: Ah just so you remember, base_url is not a php function you will have to implement it. This can help http://blog.lavoie.sl/2013/02/php-document-root-path-and-url-detection.html